# Working with json in PL/pgSQL, find entries in an array where values of object keys are in other array

Tags: json, postgresql, plpgsql

I have two json arrays like this:

```
string_array := '["a", "c"]'::json;
object_array := '[{"name": "a"}, {"name": "b"}, {"name": "c"}]'::json;
```

Consider the `string_array` as a filter for the other one. Could you please tell me how can I write a piece of PL/pgSQL code to create:

```
'[{"name": "a"}, {"name": "c"}]'
```

I've tried all sorts of ways, but each one has a different problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query will do what you want. It relies on functions that were introduced in postgreSQL 9.3 though.

```
SELECT json_agg(json)
FROM json_array_elements('[{"name": "a"}, {"name": "b"}, {"name": "c"}]'::json) as objects(json)
JOIN json_array_elements('["a", "c"]'::json) as keys(key)
    ON ((objects.json -> 'name')::text = key::text);
```